# how does uri link of firebase verification email works?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know I have similar problems of verification of emails but I want to know how does the `actionCodeSettings` works in firebase basically on this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth)..I don't understand the `uri` `android` and `ios` links thingy..I don't know how can I connect it with a link like the `sendSignInLinkToEmail` or `sendEmailVerification` becuz they both have the `actionCodeSettings`

If its on gmail how do I link it or maybe facebook or maybe twitch or whatever platform it is??

Here is my sample code

```
    const actionCodeSettings = {
        url: 'https://accounts.google.com/',
        // This must be true.
        handleCodeInApp: true,
        iOS: {
          bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
        },
        android: {
          packageName: 'com.example.android',
          installApp: true,
          minimumVersion: '12'
        },
        dynamicLinkDomain: 'example.page.link'
    }
....


    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        setLoading(true)
    
        sendEmailVerification(user,actionCodeSettings)
        // sendEmailVerification(user?.getIdToken)
        // .then(res => {
        //     console.log(res)
        // }).catch(err => {
        //     console.log(err)
        // })

        setLoading(false)

    }
```

This on my `Verification.jsx` I want to the `signInLinkEmail` but it is just similar with `sendEmailVerification` because of `actionCodeSettings` how do I fix it? I don't understand the `actionCodeSettings`...

Can anyone make an example of `verification or sendSignInLinkEmail`? Thanks a lot for response.

Answer (score 0):

You can read here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

in firebase console also, go to Authentication -> Settings and check 'Link accounts that use the same email'

whenever a user authenticate with another platform, get his email and send a verification code from its auth provider.

Comment: Does this the same in verification? This is an authentication and I don't know how providers work..could you make a sample?